# How do we arrange to keep local copies of all NuGet packages used by a solution?

Tags: nuget

We are starting up a very long-term project (let's put it this way, we need to be able to compile it not less than *fifteen* years from now). We really don't think random NuGet packages we depend on are going to live that long.

What is the right way to arrange to keep local copies of everything?

That is, we should be able to deploy to a new machine our fixed dependencies, do git clone followed by *something* followed by msbuild and everything builds *without any connection to the internet*.

Comment: Why not simply keep the "packages" folder (i.e. created after nuget installation in solution directory) under source control? Although it's not recommended.

Comment: @vendettamit: Because it's not recommended and the tools don't seem to like it.

Comment: what do you mean by "tools"? Well, There's another option. Keep a build machine's "Local Nuget cache"(`%appdata%\..\local\nuget\cache`) synced with a network share. And Keep the path(Of network share) in Nuget.config file as local source of nugets which can be shared across different dev machines.

Comment: vendettamit posts a valid solution as a comment; unfortunately it's not as good as it seems.

Comment: I used the same approach for my team to work in offline mode. Our situation was bit tricky as we had this kinda situation. So our Client had his own nuget server accessible via vpn and vpn tunnel wasn't allowing internet so we endup using a local nuget cache directory as shared resource when one of the vpn or internet was unavailable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We took election and decided that RetroCoder's approach of the local nuGet server was the right approach; however the documentation he provided was way out of date.

Better documentation to be found here: https://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds In summary:

1. Create empty C# web project
2. Add package NuGet.Server
3. Add API key to web.config `<add key="apiKey" value="password" />` under `<appSettings>`
4. Publish web application

To push new packages to it run

```
nuget.exe push path\to\package.nupkg -s http://nugetserver/webapp password
```

To push all packages for a solution run

```
find packages -name '*.nupkg' -print0 | tr '/' '\\' | xargs -0 -L 1 -I % nuget.exe push % -s http://nugetserver/webapp password
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [host](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KaEmsdf0oKU) your own local Nuget Server.

Also at the solution you can enable Nuget package restore.

You may want to keep instructions in your project on how to host the server and where the backup is located so in 15 years a survivor can revive the project.

Here is a link to some [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/overview) on Hosting your own NuGet package.

Comment: link "host" goes back here.

Comment: #*^%%% accessibility problems. I can't follow such technical videos because I can't seem them well enough.

Comment: Added a link to documentation